# Swipe View in Android/MonoAndroid?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am wondering is there a view in android that you can swipe and it goes to another view? I am using mono Android but can't seem to find anything on how to do this. I expanded my search to android but can't find anything as well.

Does anyone know a sample project that has this that I can look at and use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google released the compatibility pack with some new UI Elements, which you can download via SDK Manager.

- put the .jar file located in `sdkfolder/extras/compatibility` in your build path.
- now you can use a class called `ViewPager` which behaves like the Android Homescreen.

Or, if you are using Eclipse and ADT plugin v12 or higher, just right click your project, choose "Android Tools" and then "add compatibility package".

Comment: Can you post a link to this? Also does this work with MonoDroid?

Comment: Im not familiar with monodroid, so i cant tell. I dont have a direct download link, for the compabillity package, just download it via android sdk manager, like the normal android sdk, there is a point "compabillity package" or something like it. And if u can use 3rd party librariers in monodroid i would think the compability package will work there too, becuase ist just a library....

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no View that comes with Android that does this. There are however several 3rd party ones.

@Commonsguy extended ViewFlipper to make it recognize swipe touch events and flip views accordingly.

Check out the [ViewSwiper source code](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-viewswiper)

Edit: I am not familiar with monodroid, so I am afraid I am of no help there. And the difference between them is that ViewSwiper has extended ViewFlipper and adds support for switching views via a swipe or "fling" gesture on the screen. View flipper has no such support by default.

Comment: Do you know if I have to convert this to .net? Or can I somehow just import it into monodroid?

Comment: @Tim- Also how do I import the demo into eclipse(I really never used eclipse that much)

Comment: @Tim- So what is the difference between this and viewFlipper?

Comment: What is pagination that I see. If I swipe on the emulator it actually works?

Comment: I also tried to import(threw eclipse) the demo of the ViewSwiper but it won't let me. Says "No projects are found to import".